# How get auto rotate in iPad?

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

In my application i added UITabBarController *rootController;

in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** i done this code.
for that i wrote

```
 WaylistController *waylistNavigationControllerTemp = [[WaylistNavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WaylistNavigationController" bundle:nil];
      self.waylisyViewController = waylistNavigationControllerTemp;
      UINavigationController * waylistNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:waylisyViewController];
      [waylistNavigationControllerTemp release];

WayRoomController *wayRoomNavigationControllerrTemp = [[WayRoomNavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WayRoomNavigationController" bundle:nil];
      self.WayRoomViewController = wayRoomNavigationControllerrTemp;
      UINavigationController * wayRoomNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:WayRoomViewController];
      [wayRoomNavigationControllerrTemp release];


rootController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: WaylistNavigationController,//0
                                    WayRoomNavigationController,//1                       
                                     nil]
[rootController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

for this i am not getting auto orient always getting patriot only. any one please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your controller class to which you need the orientations.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
 // Return YES for supported orientations
  if((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLanscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight))
    return YES;

}
```

Also make sure that in your project setting you have enabled all the orientations.
In your .xib file use the autosizing to scale for both orientations.

Answer (score 0):

Check Settings in .plist file for Supported interface orientation..